# Append onto variable without duplicating value?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, while-loop, ternary-operator

I have 12 variables that contain Boolean values. Based on every Boolean input that is true, I assign a numeric value to another variable called `finalInputValue`. The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to append to this variable `finalInputValue` without duplicating a value. I have the following code so far:

```
    var finalInputValue = ""

    function findFinalInputValue(){
        if (finalInputValue == ""){
            finalInputValue = boolean1Input == true ? "527" :
                         boolean2Input == true ? "528" :
                         boolean3Input == true ? "529" :
                         boolean4Input == true ? "530" :
                         boolean5Input == true ? "531" :
                         boolean6Input == true ? "532" :
                         boolean7Input == true ? "533" :
                         boolean8Input == true ? "534" :
                         boolean9Input == true ? "535" :
                         boolean10Input == true ? "536" :
                         boolean11Input == true ? "537" :
                         boolean12Input == true ? "538" : "";
         }
         if (finalInputValue != ""){
             ...
             ...
         }
   }
   findFinalInputValue();
```

So as you can see, this block is basically assigning the first numeric value to the variable `finalInputValue`. How can I get my function to run over and over again until it has checked all 12 of the Boolean inputs? How can I append the respective numeric values for every Boolean that is true, without the function duplicating one of the values? I have not started the part of the function that append onto the first result, because I do not know how to tell the function to ignore a certain Boolean Input (if it has been appended already). Hope I have been clear. I am just looking to get an appended string of numeric values of all the "true" Boolean inputs. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? A for loop? Use of an array?

Comment: Any time you find yourself writing numbered variables like that you probably should be using an array instead. Then you can write a loop to process the array elements.

Comment: Also if you know the variable is either true/false then just do `if (variable) { ... } `

Answer (score 0):

### Quick and dirty:

```
var output = "";
if( boolean1Input  ) output += "527,";
if( boolean2Input  ) output += "528,";
if( boolean3Input  ) output += "529,";
if( boolean4Input  ) output += "530,";
if( boolean5Input  ) output += "531,";
if( boolean6Input  ) output += "532,";
if( boolean7Input  ) output += "533,";
if( boolean8Input  ) output += "534,";
if( boolean9Input  ) output += "535,";
if( boolean10Input ) output += "536,";
if( boolean11Input ) output += "537,";
if( boolean12Input ) output += "538";
return output;
```

Note this may have a trailing `,` character which you'll have to deal with.

### Quick and dirty, but using an array for output:

```
var output = [];
if( boolean1Input  ) output.push("527");
if( boolean2Input  ) output.push("528");
if( boolean3Input  ) output.push("529");
if( boolean4Input  ) output.push("530");
if( boolean5Input  ) output.push("531");
if( boolean6Input  ) output.push("532");
if( boolean7Input  ) output.push("533");
if( boolean8Input  ) output.push("534");
if( boolean9Input  ) output.push("535");
if( boolean10Input ) output.push("536");
if( boolean11Input ) output.push("537");
if( boolean12Input ) output.push("538");
return output;
```

### Succinct, but dangerous:

```
var output = [];
for( var i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ) {
    var input = eval('boolean' + i + 'Input');
    if( input ) output.push( i + 526 ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead of lots of separate variables.

```
function findFinalInputValue(inputs) {
    if (finalInputValue == "") {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i] == true) {
                finalInputValue += (527 + i).toString();
            }
        }
    }
    if (finalInputValue != "") {
        ...
    }
}

findFinalInputValue(booleanInputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use json to keep track of added values

```
Var finalvalue = {}
Var booleaninput = boolean1Input == true ? "527" :"" 
If(booleaninput != "") {
  If(typeof finalvalue.booleaninput! = "undefined") {
 //value already present 
 }else{
 //add value to json 
 Finalvalue[booleanvalue] = booleanvalue 
 } 
}
```

You can get your finalvalue after loop is completed by taking all the keys
Finalvalue.Keys()

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to store inputs with array, which makes it really convenient. Assume we have inputs like this:

```
const CODES = ["527", "528", "529", "530", "531", "532", "533", "534", "535", "536", "537", "538"];
const inputs = [boolean1Input, boolean2Input, boolean3Input, boolean4Input, boolean5Input, boolean6Input, boolean7Input, boolean8Input, boolean9Input, boolean10Input, boolean11Input, boolean12Input];
```

Then simply use this:

```
[...CODES.keys()]
    .filter(x => inputs[x])
    .map(x => CODES[x])
```

It first filters out all false inputs and then maps the remaining index to corresponding code.

However, if using array for inputs is not possible, I would writes code like this:

```
[
    boolean1Input  && "527",
    boolean2Input  && "528",
    boolean3Input  && "529",
    boolean4Input  && "530",
    boolean5Input  && "531",
    boolean6Input  && "532",
    boolean7Input  && "533",
    boolean8Input  && "534",
    boolean9Input  && "535",
    boolean10Input && "536",
    boolean11Input && "537",
    boolean12Input && "538",
].filter(x => x) // filter out false values
```